# Add a table to a debezium connector

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

I have a Debezium connector, connecting to SQL Server, with one table in the `table.include.list` configuration parameter. I wanted to add another table, which I've added to the `table.include.list` parameter, though my connector isn't picking it up.

My previous `table.include.list` looked like this:
`"table.include.list":"dbo.Users"`

My current `table.include.list` looks like this:
`"table.include.list":"dbo.Users,dbo.charlie"`

I restarted Kafka, restarted the connector in Debezium, though when I look at the connector status in bash, I still see the old `table.include.list` value. Is there something else which needs to be done to get the connector to refresh what it has in the configuration file?

Debezium version: 1.2.5.Final
Kafka version: 2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

restart connector will not get latest config, you have to re-deploy(post) the connector with new config.

Comment: Good point. I see that, though redeploying the connector, while it got the new list to show in the connector status, it has not resulted in the new table being added to my event hub. This solved just a part of the issue